# Add specific class if a class has siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to loop through all elements of a specific class, then add a separate class to them if they have siblings. I can't figure out the correct syntax to achieve this.

```
$('.someclass').each(function(index, object) {
  if (object.siblings().size() > 0) {
    object.addClass('otherclass');
  }
});
```

Comment: Some sample html would have been nice for this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be

```
$('.someclass').each(function(index, dom) {
  if ($(dom).siblings().length > 0) {
    $(dom).addClass('otherclass');
  }
});
```

The [`.size()`](https://api.jquery.com/size/) method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. The `.size()` method is functionally equivalent to the `.length` property; however, the `.length` property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

We can not call `.siblings()` method directly on `dom` object, as it is native [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement). That is why we did `$(dom)`, to covert to JQuery object, and now we can do `$(dom).siblings()`.

Here is an working example.

```js
$('.third-item').each(function(index, dom) {
  if ($(dom).siblings().length > 0) {
    $(dom).addClass('otherclass');
  }
});
```

```css
.otherclass {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <p>paragraph</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="third-item">list item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
      <li>list item 4</li>
      <li>list item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 1</li>
      <li>list item 2</li>
      <li class="third-item">list item 3</li>
      <li>list item 4</li>
      <li>list item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this.parentNode.childNodes.length - 1 is the easiest way to get the number of siblings. For addClass, you need to make wrap `object` in jQuery (`addClass` is a jQuery function)

```
$('.someclass').each(function(index, object) {
  if (object.parentNode.childNodes.length - 1 > 0) {
    $(object).addClass('otherclass');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to just apply styles, you can use [`only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) to add styles and no JavaScript is needed.

```css
.wrapper {
  outline: 2px dotted silver;
  margin: 1em;
}

.foo {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.foo:only-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="foo">alone</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="foo">not alone</div>
  <div>world</div>
</div>
```